# Video is not running in my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, video

Video is not running in my ubuntu 14.04 LTS. When I run it, it says "The application videos has closed unexpectedly." and shows like the following image. What should I do now?[image]

Comment: Try reinstalling totem! does vlc work?

Answer (score 1):

You must report this bug in launchpad. For this open your terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and type:-

```
ubuntu-bug totem
```

**If you are tired of filing a bug :-**

- Try reinstalling totem(the default Video player in Ubuntu) from software centre:-

[image: Install via the software center]

or from terminal:-

```
sudo apt-get install totem
```

- Also instead of doing that you can install some other media player,like VLC.

You can do it from the software centre :-

[image: Install via the software center]

or from terminal:-

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Let me also make you aware that due to Ubuntu's Free Software philosophy they can't include non-free media formats out of the box.

> "Ubuntu strives to make all of the most important software available to
>   its users automatically. However patent and copyright restrictions
>   (see Ubuntu License Policy) complicate distribution of software to
>   support non-free formats.
>
> However, you can install the ability to play popular non-free media
>   formats, including DVD, MP3, Quicktime, and Windows Media formats"
>
> (look [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats) for more info)

So you need to install those formats manually(if you are going to use totem)by install the `Ubuntu restricted extras` from the software center:

[image: Install via the software center]

or from your terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Answer (score 0):

you can download VLC media player from the store, or download ubuntu restricted extras (codecs for the default media player).

Answer (score 0):

the best video player which i found that can play almost all types of video is 'mpv'
you can install it by typing this command in terminal

```
sudo apt install mpv
```

i hope this will fix your issue!